# Powershell in-line "if" for send-mailmessage

Tags: powershell-2.0

Is it possible in PowerShell to add a parameter on a cmdlet call ONLY if there is a variable to pass?

E.g.

```
Send-MailMessage -To $recipients (if($copy -ne "") -cc $copy) ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the way you've written above but you can [splat the parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx), building the hash with conditions, so you only have one call to `send-mailmessage`. An example from a script I wrote a few months ago:

```
#Set up default/standard/common parameters
$MailParams = @{
"Subject"="This is my subject";
"BodyAsHtml" = $true;
"From" = $MailFrom;
"To" = $MailTo;
"SmtpServer" = $SMTPServer;
};

#On the last day of the month, attach a logfile.
if ((Get-Date).AddDays(1).Day -eq 1) {
$attachment = $LogFilePath;
$ReportContent = "Full log for the the preceding month is attached.<br><br>" + $ReportContent;
$MailParams.Add("Attachments",$attachment);
}

send-mailmessage @MailParms
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
$MailParams = @{
"Subject"="This is my subject";
"From" = $MailFrom;
"To" = $recipients;
"SmtpServer" = $SMTPServer;
};

if (($copy -ne [string]::empty) -and ($copy -ne $null)) {
$MailParms.Add("CC",$copy);
}

send-mailmessage @MailParms
```